# feature weights in structured support vector machine

Tags: svm

I like to find the weight vector for input-space features in a [structured SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_support_vector_machine). The idea is to identify the most important set of input-space features (based on the magnitude of their corresponding weights). I know that in a binary SVM the weight vector can be written as a [linear combination of examples](http://pyml.sourceforge.net/doc/howto.pdf), and the magnitude of those weights represents how much they were effective for the prediction problem at hand. But how do you compute the same for an SSVM?

Comment: Can you clarify? It sounds like you are looking for feature importance, but the link you give talks about writing weights as a linear combination of input, which is not the same thing at all.

Comment: @SeanOwen, actually, what I wanted to say was since you can compute the weight vector using the dual variables and the input examples (in a binary SVM), and the actual weights corresponding to features tell us the relative importance of the features [Gene Selection for Cancer Classification using
Support Vector Machines
](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.70.9598&rep=rep1&type=pdf)